# Protractor exited with error code 100 when run config.js

Tags: protractor, jasmine2.0, jasmine-reporters

A few days ago, my protractor was working fine. But yesterday when I tried to run the same tests, I got:

```
E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 'jasmine-reporters'
Require stack:
- D:\Repos\POS\config\config_c80_checkScreen.js
- C:\Users\ingridd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js
- C:\Users\ingridd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js
- C:\Users\ingridd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js
- C:\Users\ingridd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
   at onPrepare (D:\Repos\POS\config\config_c80_checkScreen.js:62:28)
   at C:\Users\ingridd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:46:49
   at Function.promise (C:\Users\ingridd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:682:9) 
   at Object.runFilenameOrFn_ (C:\Users\ingridd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:38:16)
   at C:\Users\ingridd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:98:27
   at _fulfilled (C:\Users\ingridd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)      
Closing report
[11:03:30] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

On my project folder, I have the protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter folder as you can see on the screenshot

[jasmine2 folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RFSQ.png)

Please see where the ENV var is located

[env var](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajITX.png)

The last thing I tried was to update the web driver and install the latest protractor. But I still get the same error.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 100 is RUNNERS_FAILED_EXIT_CODE which is because there is an unexpected error. The error looks like you are missing the `jasmine-reporters`. `npm install -S jasmine-reporters` should fix it.

Comment: yes this worked. But now I getting Error 105 Error: Cannot find module 'protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter' I also tried ```npm install -g  protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter```

Comment: You should install these locally. I would read up on `-D` and `-S` and install them locally. More than likely, the require call is looking at the local node_modules directory.